# Why is setLightLevel for Minecraft not working correctly?

Tags: java, minecraft

So i started developing my mod for minectraft. One of the block it adds should be more powerfull version of glowstone. So this is the script:

```java
import net.minecraft.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;

public class FeralFlareBlock extends BlockBase
{

    public FeralFlareBlock(String name, Material material) 
    {
        super(name, material);

        setSoundType(SoundType.GLASS);
        setHardness(0.3F);
        setResistance(0.3F);
        setHarvestLevel("pickaxe", 1);
        setLightLevel(100.0F);
        setLightOpacity(1);

    }

}
```

There is the setLightLevel function, i have it set to 100 even tho glowstone is 15 so theoretically this should be more powerfull. It isn't. Don't know what im doing wrong, please help me. Thx

Comment: a quick search told me the value should be between 0.0f and 1.0f. 1 being the max value

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

The `setLightLevel` method does take values between `0.0` (darkest) and `1.0` (brightest).

So a value of `100.0F` is invalid.

Also see some thread I found when searching for your issue: [[1.11] setLightLevel not producing light when block is placed in world](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61702-111-setlightlevel-not-producing-light-when-block-is-placed-in-world/):

> `Item#setLightLevel` takes a float between 0.0F and 1.0F, instead of going from 0 to 15. If you want to have the max light level, you use 1.0F.

For reference, here is a link to *a* javadoc: [Block#setLightLevel](https://skmedix.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs/javadoc/forge/1.9.4-12.17.0.2051/net/minecraft/block/Block.html#setLightLevel-float-).

---

> I have it set to 100 even tho glowstone is 15 so theoretically this should be more powerfull. It isn't.

The brightest light level in Minecraft is `15` (received by a value of `1.0` with `setLightLevel`). You **can not** make anything brighter than this. Minecraft does not support brighter values.

---

### Translate from 0-15

You can easily convert minecrafts light levels (0 to 15) to this method with simple math:

```
// Takes values between 0 and 15 (both inclusive) and converts to 0 to 1.0.
private static double translateLightLevelToFloat(int lightLevel) {
    if (ligthLevel < 0 || lightLevel > 15) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Light level must be between 0 and 15 (both inclusive)");
    }

    return lightLevel / 15.0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The maximum lightlevel is 15. So it cannot get lighter than glowstone.

https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Light

> There are 16 light
>   levels, which are specified by an integer from 0 (the minimum) to 15
>   (the maximum).

Comment: Correct, but the `setLightLevel` method takes values between `0.0` and `1.0`, not integers from `0` to `15`.

Comment: Thats right, but the lightlevel cannot exeed 15, so any value higher than 1.0 won't make any differences. Thats my statement